# Finding branches containing a particular revision? (Find merge information)

Tags: svn, merge

How do I find all all the branches that contain a particular change revision?

For instance, I commit revision 123, then I merge it to branch RC1, but not RC2.

What command(s) can I use to get that information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to list all branches, and for each one listing the revision being merged in a given branch.
That information is stored in the [property `svn:mergeinfo`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.mergeinfo.html):

```
svn mergeinfo SOURCE_URL[@REV] [TARGET[@REV]]
```

> Query information related to merges (or potential merges) between `SOURCE-URL` and `TARGET`.
>   If the `--show-revs` option is not provided, display revisions which have been merged from `SOURCE-URL` to `TARGET`.
>   Otherwise, display either merged or eligible revisions as specified by the `--show-revs` option.

Example:

> Find out which changesets your have been merged from your trunk directory into your test branch:

```
$ svn propget svn:mergeinfo ^/branches/test
/branches/other:3-4
/trunk:11-13,14,16
```

So for a given source and target:

```
$ svn mergeinfo --show-revs merged ^/trunk ^/branches/test
r11
r12
r13
r14
r16
$
```